# express sessionstate which i create is undefined after every making request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm making a website by express js with view as handlebars. I use express-session to save cart information. I have the problem that every time I request to add product to cart, my req.session.cart is undefined so it is always created new req.session.cart and every time I add product to cart only 1 product can be added. But when i run it on post man, it works as expected

cartController.js

```
const {add, initCart, cartDetail} = require('../../services/cartService')

const getCart = async(req, res)=>{
  console.log('get cart',req.session)
  console.log(req.session.cart)
  console.log(req.session.test)
  res.json(await cartDetail(req.session.cart));
}

const addItemToCart = (req, res)=>{
  console.log('Vao add to cart ')
  console.log(req.body)

  const {productId} = req.body;
  req.session.test = 'test';
  if(req.session.cart){
    console.log('da co cart')
  }
  if(!req.session.cart){
    req.session.cart = initCart();
  } 

  console.log(' before add item to cart',req.session)
  add(productId, req.session.cart)
  console.log(req.session.cart)
  console.log(' after add item to cart',req.session)
  res.json(req.session.cart)

}

module.exports = {
  getCart,
  addItemToCart
}
```

cartService.js

```
const {getSpecificProductById}= require('./productService')

exports.add = (productId, cart)=>{
  const foundProduct = cart.products.find(product=>product.id === productId);
  if(foundProduct){
    foundProduct.quantity = foundProduct.quantity+1;
  }else{
    cart.products.push({id: productId, quantity: 1});
  }
}

exports.cartDetail = async(cart)=>{
  const cartDetails = {...cart};
  cartDetails.products  = await Promise.all(cartDetails.products.map(async product=>{
    const productInfo = await getSpecificProductById(product.id);
    return {
      ...product,
      name: productInfo.name,
      price: productInfo.price,
      image: productInfo.image,
    }
  }))

  return cartDetails;
}

exports.initCart = ()=>(
  {
    products: []
  }
)
```

app.js

```
const hbs  = require('hbs')
var indexRouter = require("./routes/home");
var usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
const {aboutRouter} = require("./routes/aboutRouter")
const {shoppingCartRouter} = require("./routes/shoppingCartRouter")
const {checkoutRouter} = require("./routes/checkoutRouter")
const productRouter = require('./routes/productRouter')
const authRouter = require("./auth/authRouter");
const profileRouter = require("./routes/profileRouter")
const authApiRouter = require('./auth/api')
const productApiRouter = require('./routes/APIRoutes/productApiRouter');
const cartApiRouter = require('./routes/APIRoutes/cartApiRouter');

const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require('./auth/passport/index')

const MySQLStore = require('connect-mysql')(session)
const options = {
  config:{
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password: '280502',
    database: 'session-db'
  }
}

const paginate = require('express-paginate')

const cors = require('cors')


var app = express();

// view engine setup

app.use(cors())
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
hbs.handlebars.registerHelper("minus", (a,b)=>{
  return a-b
})
var blocks = {};

hbs.handlebars.registerHelper('extend', function(name, context) {
  var block = blocks[name];
  if (!block) {
    block = blocks[name] = [];
  }

  block.push(context.fn(this)); // for older versions of handlebars, use block.push(context(this));
});

hbs.handlebars.registerHelper('block', function(name) {
  var val = (blocks[name] || []).join('\n');

  // clear the block
  blocks[name] = [];
  return val;
});

app.use(paginate.middleware(5, 20))
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'very secret keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: false, 
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3,
    expires: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3,
  },
  store: new MySQLStore(options)
}))
app.use(passport.authenticate('session'));
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
  res.locals.user = req.user
  next();
});

app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/about", aboutRouter);
app.use("/products", productRouter)
app.use("/api/products", productApiRouter)
app.use("/auth", authRouter);

//api
app.use('/api/auth',authApiRouter);
app.use("/cart", shoppingCartRouter)

app.use("/api/cart", cartApiRouter);
app.use("/checkout", checkoutRouter)
app.use("/profile", profileRouter)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is my first time having this problem. It took up a lot of my time. Can anyone help me to solve this problem. Thanks everyone

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but express-session has a known issue where it doesn't send secure cookies over localhost. See: https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/837

Comment: I have a reference on the express-session page [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session), it is said that if you are in a dev environment, don't set secure for cookies or set it to false to be able to send cookies via localhost. However I tried that way but still no success @JoeC.

Comment: Can you check if the browser receives the express-session's cookie at all (inspect element)? If the browser receives a cookie that is secure=false and also cors, which you are using, it won't send the cookie back to the server on future requests for security reasons. So if you see the browser is receiving the cookie but the cookie is not sent back to the server, this might be the issue.

Comment: I got cookies in application>cookies>127.0.0.1:3000, however in Session Storage it has nothing.  @JoeC.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this problem? @JoeC.

Comment: So probably the cookie has SameSite=None (i.e. cors enabled) but Secure=false. If you can turn off cors, that is easiest. But if you need cors, then it is annoying because it is a bug in express-session: it is supposed to work with Secure=true on localhost, but doesn't (see https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/837). I think one way is to set up something like nginx on your dev machine to simulate a production environment, that way you can have secure=true and localhost.